# parsley js + jquery tabs (ajax)

Tags: jquery-tabs, parsley.js

I trying to use parley js with jquery ui tabs, the content of the tabs are loaded via url (ajax).

Parsley does not work when fetching the content with ajax.

I also tried to re-intialize parsley on the form with the ajax load event but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Working now, I added parsley initialization on the form in the ajax page.